# Deploying Spring Boot war with Jersey in Wildfly

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, wildfly

I have a project where I use Spring boot to build a stand alone jar.  It uses jersey to serve up the back end, and I have it configured to also host an angular/js front end in the resources folder.

The solution I would like is that this can be standalone in the jar file, and run by itself. But also have a configuration where we build it as a war file, and run it alongside another war inside of Wildfly.

I can get it to compile a war, but as soon as I try to start it up, it appears I get issues with Tomcat.  Has anyone tried running an environment like this?

Here is the exception logs.

```
    11:14:22,316 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-9) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final-patch9.jar:8.2.1.Final-patch9]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017327: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadSci(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:207)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:128)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final-patch9.jar:8.2.1.Final-patch9]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017327: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadSci(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:199)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more from [Module "deployment.testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadSci(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:191)
    ... 7 more

11:14:22,321 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017327: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017327: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more from [Module \"deployment.testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
11:14:22,323 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017327: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017327: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more from [Module \"deployment.testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
11:14:22,344 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
11:14:25,469 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war (runtime-name: testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war) in 3146ms
11:14:25,470 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL

[2018-03-09 11:14:25,528] Artifact testApp:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2018-03-09 11:14:25,528] Artifact testApp:war: java.lang.Exception: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017327: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS017327: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more from [Module \"deployment.testApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"}}
```

Here is my current pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dematic.wms</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-workflow</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>app-workflow</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <spring.version>5.0.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <!--<hsqldb.version>2.4.0</hsqldb.version>-->
        <dbh2.version>1.4.195</dbh2.version>
        <!--<derby.version>10.11.1.1</derby.version>-->

        <wildfly.version>9.0.2.Final</wildfly.version>
        <cargo.container.id>wildfly9x</cargo.container.id>
        <cargo.container.url>http://download.jboss.org/wildfly/${wildfly.version}/wildfly-${wildfly.version}.zip
        </cargo.container.url>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>tomcat-embed-core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>tomcat-embed-websocket</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>jdk8</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>1.8</jdk>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>reserve-network-port</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>reserve-network-port</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <portNames>
                                        <portName>appserver.port</portName>
                                        <portName>appserver.ajp.port</portName>
                                        <portName>appserver.transaction.port</portName>
                                    </portNames>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <configuration>
                                <properties>
                                    <cargo.servlet.port>${appserver.port}</cargo.servlet.port>
                                    <cargo.jboss.ajp.port>${appserver.ajp.port}</cargo.jboss.ajp.port>
                                    <cargo.jboss.transaction.statusManager.port>
                                        ${appserver.transaction.port}
                                    </cargo.jboss.transaction.statusManager.port>
                                    <cargo.jboss.configuration>standalone-full</cargo.jboss.configuration>
                                </properties>
                            </configuration>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <port>${appserver.port}</port>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: I did some weird googling and this came up: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=https://my.oschina.net/xulong1/blog/1538803&prev=search. The blog is originally in Chinese so I fed it through Google Translate. It looks like you may be able to get around this by excluding logback.

Comment: If you are deploying to Wildfly (or any container) you shouldn’t have any embedded Tomcat jars in your war. What does you pom.xml or build.gradle look like? You probably need to declare Tomcat as a provided dependency so it doesn’t get packaged in your war file.

Comment: I'll post my POM when i get a chance, but I've tried everything i can think of to exclude it

Comment: I posted the POM.  Now this is my current iteration, I've gone through many.  Mainy trying to find out how to get rid of Tomcat. I think it's being pulled in by the parent right now.