# spring boot application deployment failed on jboss eap 7

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I am not able to deploy the my Spring BOOT REST Application on JBOSS EAP 7 Server.

However, its running fine after deployment on  Apache Tomcat 8 Server.

**Application Main Class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"org.nic"})
@PropertySource(value="classpath:database.properties")
public class PopulationApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(PopulationApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(PopulationApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>org.nic.PopulationApplication</start-class>
        </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>  


        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

It's throwing the following error at server logs

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'httpPutFormContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Failed to link com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/ReferenceType (Module "deployment.nhpmapi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Cannot inherit from final class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
    ... 35 more
```

My Server environment only had JBOSS EAP 7.

I had research to solve the issue but could not find any success.

I had last option to remove Spring BOOT configuration into order to run on JBOSS EAP 7

Comment: I had found related article `https://ilya-murzinov.github.io/articles/spring-boot-jboss/` but it seems too much configuration for running a simple web application on jboss eap 7.

Answer (score 12):

I had the exact same problem and struggled for two days. Finally found a solution! 
`java.lang.VerifyError` is usually caused when there is inconsistency of classes. 
As shown in the error message, it's caused by `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind`

Since Jboss has its internal Jackson module, and its version is different from your application specified. 

To solve the problem, add `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and put it under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8"/>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310"/>
            <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider" />
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

It will avoid implicit dependencies and solve the problem.

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42461799/6555215) and [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-deployment-tests/spring-boot-deployment-test-wildfly/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49198082/6555215) thanks to them!

For more information: 
[Causes of getting a java.lang.VerifyError](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518002/6555215)

[What is jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://kb.novaordis.com/index.php/Jboss-deployment-structure.xml)

[Module Dependencies](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.1/html/development_guide/chap-class_loading_and_modules#Module_Dependencies)

Comment: Thank you, friend.

Comment: This is the perfect fix

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Spring is not able to instantiate beans from the WAR. Can you check classes inside are visible and are loaded properly?

Seems like class loading issue.

Comment: `Can you check classes inside are visible and are loaded properly` How to do it?

Comment: Can you share your project structure? Where are you placing spring Jars, is it inside WAR lib folder?